# Transparent Date time picker in react native

Tags: android, react-native, datetimepicker

Is there a way to implement a transparent date time picker as shown in attached screenshot in android? I'm using [react-native date time picker](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) plugin. But in android this opens a modal. I want it to be customised as shown in the screenshot with this transparent background

[image]

Comment: according to their readme.md a spinner could only be used in IOS
https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#display-optional

Comment: Yes, I've read it. Even this plugin provides a spinner design for android but it is showing in a modal. Is there any way to achieve this kinda design in android? @yairmea

Comment: You can try to use a different module such as 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-scroll-picker
However, you will have to define your own data source

Comment: Ok, so i need to give the the hrs and minutes as separate data source , that's kinda hectic right

Comment: Exactly. you will have do define the hrs/ minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This package, [react-native date picker](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker), gives you a time picker with transparent background. You can achieve your desired design by:

```xml
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker'

<DatePicker
  date={date}
  onDateChange={setDate}
  mode="time"
  androidVariant="nativeAndroid"
  textColor="#ffffff"
/>
```

Additionally, change the separator color by adding this to `styles.xml`:

```xml
<item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
```